# Limit the length of a Python list

Tags: python, list, limit

How would I set a list that only holds up to ten elements?

I'm obtaining input names for a list using the following statement:

```
ar = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

and would like to limit the number of inputs a user can give

Comment: Do you want to prevent the user, or tell them afterwards there were too many value? Or just ignore the extra values, possibly giving a message that you've done so?

Comment: why do you convert to integer when you want to input names???

Answer (score 26):

After getting the `ar` list, you may discard the remaining items via *list slicing* as:

```
 ar = ar[:10]    # Will hold only first 10 nums
```

In case you also want to raise error if list has more items, you may check it's length as:

```
 if len(ar) > 10:
      raise Exception('Items exceeds the maximum allowed length of 10')
```

*Note:* In case you are making the length check, you need to make it before slicing the list.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to continue to add items to the list, but return only the most recent 5 items:

```
list1 = ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1"]
list1.append("f1")
list1[-5:]
```

Comment: This may lead a memory leak

Answer (score 4):

The list-like data structure [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) provides this by default through the `maxlen` argument.

```
from collections import deque

numbers = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13"

arr = list(map(int, numbers.split()))
arr_bounded = deque(map(int, numbers.split()), maxlen=10)

print("Unlimited:", arr)
print("Limit__10:", arr_bounded)
```

**Output**

```
Unlimited: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
Limit__10: deque([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], maxlen=10)
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a custom class overwriting the list class to do this for me

```
class LimitedLengthList(list):
    def __init__(self, seq=(), length=math.inf):
        self.length = length

        if len(seq) > length:
            raise ValueError("Argument seq has too many items")

        super(LimitedLengthList, self).__init__(seq)

    def append(self, item):
        if len(self) < self.length:
            super(LimitedLengthList, self).append(item)

        else:
            raise Exception("List is full")
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfecting @Deskjokey's answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63200549/8462064

This returns the 10 most recent items, also preventing memory leaks

```
list1 = ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1" , "a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2"]
list1.append("a3")
del list1[:-10]
list1.append("b3")
del list1[:-10]
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this post with a google search.

Yes, the following just expands on Moinuddin Quadri's answer (which I upvoted), but heck, this is what works for my requirements!

**Python Program**

```
def lifo_insert(item, da_mem_list):
    da_mem_list.insert(0, item)    
    return da_mem_list[:3]

# test

lifo_list = []
lifo_list = lifo_insert('a', lifo_list)
print('1 rec:', lifo_list)
lifo_list = lifo_insert('b', lifo_list)
lifo_list = lifo_insert('c', lifo_list)
print('3 rec:', lifo_list)
lifo_list = lifo_insert('d', lifo_list)
print('ovflo:', lifo_list)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 rec: ['a']
3 rec: ['c', 'b', 'a']
ovflo: ['d', 'c', 'b']
```

Answer (score -5):

You can also do something like this.

```
n = int(input())
a = [None] * n
```

It will create a list with limit n.