# How to set the length of a str list from an int variable

Tags: python

I've been trying to find a method to set the final output variable's length to be the same length as a specified user input variable called 'length' that asks a user how long the output should be before storing it and then trying to convert it to type int just to make sure that an integer was submitted which of course works just fine.

Tried using the range/len functions and even creating a for loop to iterate over the text 'length' amount of times and store the result in a new variable all together but nothing seems to work out.

The input is just a number, I'm asking the user how long they want the string to be which is a concatenation of a few different types of lists and stored as one string variable.

For example:

Print: What length should the surprise be?

- Take input  for exmaple '5' which should be a number and check to make sure.
- Add the lists together then set the length of the new variable to the length of '5'

Print: Your string is: ABCDE

Comment: What does it mean to "set the final output variable's length"? The length of a string is how many characters it contains. If you want it to be shorter, you need to throw away some characters; if you want it to be longer, you need to add some characters. How do you want to decide which characters to add or remove?

Comment: Can you show us what you need with an example? and actual work you have done.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "Unclear what you're asking" since I can't figure out what the question is asking for. Could this question possibly be a duplicate of [Python padding strings of different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47803871/python-padding-strings-of-different-length)? Not voting as duplicate because I can't understand the question well enough to be certain.

Comment: Hmm... Possibly what you have is a `list` of `str` objects, and you want to limit the number of `str` objects in the list? Is the goal simply to *limit*, or do you also want to *pad* the list to a given length if it's too short? If you just want to limit, the answer is here: [Limit the length of a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696005/limit-the-length-of-a-python-list).

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify the question, and add what you've tried so far. See [ask] for more tips.

Comment: Thanks, made it more descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first treat the input as a string and use an array to set the size to a input value.

```
string1 = 'ABCD'
string2 = 'EFGH'
n = string1 + string2
lengthStr = int(input("What is desired string length? "))
print('n:', n, 'desired length:', lengthStr)
x = n[0:lengthStr]
print('Updated string', x)
```

This isn't the best solution, for example if used entered length 0 python would error out.

Comment: The input is just a number, I'm asking the user how long they want the string to be which is a concatenation of a few different types of lists and stored as one string variable.

For example:

Print: What length should the surprise be?

- Take input  for exmaple '5' which should be a number and check to make sure.

- Add the lists together then set the length of the new variable to the length of '5' 

Print: Your string is: ABCDE

Comment: I updated my answer for what I think you are looking for. I really just removed the conversion of the input string to a integer though.

Comment: Worked great! Now I just have to figure out what to do if the user wants a length of 100 or greater as the combined lists seem to always deliver just shy of that length.

Thanks for your help.